# ng2-stomp-service does not connect to Spring server in https

Tags: spring, angular, stomp

I have a client Angular 2 application, and a Spring boot (1.4.1.RELEASE) server application. I wrote the client code to send a connection request to the server using the angular library ng2-stomp-service, and the server code to manage the connection request.

All works fine when using http, but when using https I see a connection error (HTTP/1.1 400) in the javascript console:

```
GET https://tomcatunisvid.lunagest.com/unisvid/workflow/046/mmesis4u/websocket [HTTP/1.1 400  358ms]

Firefox non può stabilire una connessione con il server wss://tomcatunisvid.lunagest.com/unisvid/workflow/046/mmesis4u/websocket.
```

In Firefox I found the request and the response headers:

-- REQUEST HEADERS

```
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encodinggzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control no-cache
Connection keep-alive, Upgrade
Host tomcatunisvid.lunagest.com
Origin https://tomcatunisvid.lunagest.com 
Pragma no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key J2Aqm3n2r6vcE7F8SrPr3w==
Sec-WebSocket-Version 13
Upgrade websocket
User-AgentMozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
```

-- RESPONSE HEADERS

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Access-Control-Allow-Originh ttps://tomcatunisvid.lunagest.com
Cache-Control no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection close
Date Mon, 06 Nov 2017 11:50:42 GMT
Expires 0
Pragma no-cache
Server Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)Transfer-Encoding chunked
Vary Origin
X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
X-Frame-Options DENY
X-XSS-Protection1; mode=block
```

and the response is empty.

Here is my relevant client code:

```
// In the constructor, where stomp is a StompService:

stomp.configure({
  host: this.url,
  debug: true,
  queue: { 'init': false, '/user/queue/user/reply': false },
  // headers: { 'upgrade': 'WebSocket' }
});

// in another method:

this.stomp.startConnect().
  then(() => this.openSocket_OK_Callback(this)).
  catch((error) => this.openSocket_KO_Callback(this, error));
```

Here is my relevant server code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends 
AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/wfm");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        SessionDisconnectionListener sdl = new SessionDisconnectionListener();

        String endpoint = "/workflow";

        registry.addEndpoint(endpoint).
            setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();

        registry.addEndpoint(endpoint).setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy())).
            setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();

    }

}
```

Any hints how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I put here the answer I found after some debugging, in case it is useful to others. In the release environment Tomcat was proxied by Apache Http Server. The solution in this case was to remove Apache Http Server and configure Https directly on Tomcat.